# I want to command a 12V DC motor with the output of a clock alarm

Tags: dc-motor, power-electronics

I want to command a 12 V DC motor with the output of a clock alarm. The output of the clock alarm is a 1V (pp) square  signal of 100 Hz. I just want my motor supplied when alarm is on and then stop when alarm period is over, meaning when square signal becomes zero.

Edit: 
[image]

R5,L1 and V3 are the DC motor model.
Q3 reference is TIP31 instead of 2N3904

Comment: Could you perhaps use an existing timer switch instead?   To build something like this yourself, first you need to characterize the current (not just ordinary, but also start and stall) of the motor.  It may be simpler to use a relay module as that has a fairly wide switching capability compared to a semiconductor (transistor) switch.  Then you may need something like a comparator or op-amp to boost the signal to the level needed by the relay's driver circuit, and perhaps a capacitor to filter the ringing pulses to a steady signal.  An MCU (or Arduino etc) approach is not unreasonable either.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Thats the point I want to profit from the already existing output of a little alarm clock that I have I don't need extra costs and circuitry I was thinking about using a transistor and then a filter to get the steady signal but I thought if there's someone who knows another way to stabilise the output signal of the transistor.

Comment: you will need a transistor to act as a switch and a capacitor to make the pulses of a 100 Hz a somewhat constant signal, in order to drive the transistor. For more details, provide more info on the components you want to use

Comment: Thanks thece.with Which signal would I hook the capacitor, input signal or output signal of the transistor?

Comment: @fakherhabib are you familiar with this kind of things? The capacitor should be connected to the pin that provides the 1Vpp @ 100Hz and to ground. Transistor's base connects to the capacitor, collector to the DC motor and emitter to the ground. As I said before, for more details you have to provide more informations.

Comment: No this is the first time lmao.

Comment: what kind of a clock are you using?

Comment: @fakherhabib - I see that you have added a schematic to your question, but you didn't explain anything about it. For example: Is this something where you have just run the simulation (since you used a model for the motor component), or have you actually constructed the circuit? If you constructed it, then how well does it work? Why did you change component values, from those given in the answer which suggested a similar design? In short: Without a clear explanation of *why* you added that schematic, *why* you chose those components, and *what* behaviour you now see, it's difficult to help you.

Comment: Also, depending on the motor drawn by your motor, it's entirely possible that a 2N3904 will not work, and that you'll need 2-stage current amplification in your driver section. Finally, I'll guarantee that R1 is much too large.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this might work for your application:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsVlJq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Q3 serves as a class-C amplifier that generates a 12V waveform at a higher current (if it was unloaded) which then goes through a peak-detector that drives a switch transistor (Q1).

I put some guesses at what were the impedances of the alarm drive signal and the motor, and a 2N3904 to drive a motor is probably not a good choice, but you should get the idea.

If you use a low-threshold NFET as the drive transistor you should be able to simplify some of the circuitry, but 1Vpp does not leave much room to work with.

Looking at it more carefully, if you remove R3 and D3 the circuit would still work.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjoxUG.png)</sup>

Comment: + the flyback diode of the motor

Comment: @thece normally true, but given the very slow waveforms driving Q1 the switch on/off of the motor would probably be too slow to matter. I would be somewhat more concerned with power dissipation on Q1 during the switching periods.

Comment: Understood, but wouldn't hurt either. I would like to ask, what's the purpose of D2 and if we could skip the hole Q3 amplification step. 1V seems to be just enough to drive Q1.

Comment: @thece if it was 1V DC, the source impedance was low enough, and the motor consumed low enough current perhaps. But 1Vpp is 0.5Vdc which would not activate a transistor switch, or you can have a 12V 100Hz PWM (I.e., 6V dc effectively) with a maximum current of beta*0.3V/ source resistance (<10mA, 5mA average in this case). It is hard enough with the amplification stage in place, but this allows you to use even a Darlington for Q1 if you need more current, this would not be possible otherwise.

Comment: @thece D2 is there to act as a DC recovery/voltage doubler gate bias to drive Q2. On the positive cycle the base goes to ~12.2V which provides 0.8V of bias in the negative cycle (barely enough). It could be substituted by a voltage divider to provide somewhat more bias to Q2.

Comment: I think that 1 Vpp in actually 0 - 1 V (not -0.5 - +0.5). It would be weird for the clock to have positive and negative polarity. With this in mind, we only need a capacitor to make the signal ~1V constant. This will also affect the buzzer, so in order to "isolate" them we could use a voltage follower before the cap.

Comment: @thece you need a capacitor AND a diode, thus diode losses are the problem. You would have at best 0.8V to work with if you use a Schottky diode, but more likely 0.7V or less which wouldn’t be very useful.

Comment: The clock alarm output signal is actually a 1Vpp@100 hz for 4 periods then zero for 4 periods during one minute. I have an idea that instead of stabilising the signal why not making it a 1vpp@100 hz during one minute and using it as pwm to drive the dc motor is it possible ? How can I do it ? Is there any other solution ?                                                                      Ps: the dc motor is actually a 12 V fuel pump.

Comment: @fakherhabib 1Vpp is not much to play with (and you have not specified other critical parameters such as source impedance). 50% duty cycle means that at best you would have 6V on your 12V motor with PWM. I put together pretty much what I considered the bare minimum circuitry, it is already at the edge of functionality. Conceptually simpler, although larger, circuits are obviously possible.

Comment: Thank you for the circuitry it helpes me.I ve actually accomplished my idea.what I ve done is filtering the original signal then amplifying it then another filter to get 5Vpp(5v/0v) @2hz of 50 % duty cycle. Then using it to command a smart high side power switch of maximum 1.8 amps load current. My supply can draw 1.66 amps to the load. The problem is that the power switch gets hot quickly wich affects the fuel pump and make it slow down. BTS410E2  is the power switch reference.

Comment: I don't know how to determine source impedence.

Comment: @fakherhabib add a resistive load and measure the output. If it doesn’t change, your output impedance is much less than your load, if it does drop you calculate the equivalent voltage divider.

Comment: @Edgar Brown  could u give me some feedback on the circuit above. It works fine for me except for the power switch transistor it gets hot quickly.

Comment: @fakherhabib Theoretically your circuit should not work at all. There must be some parasitic leakage providing the much needed bias.